# How to automatically measure lines in PPT based on certain color codes

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I am new in VBA programming and this is my first time to write a VBA code for PPT. I had a few experience with VBA Excel.

So my problem is that I have a repetitive task of measuring autoshape lines in a PPT presentation at work. By measuring, I mean getting the height and width of the line in inches and multiplying to a certain conversion factor that I will provide.

Here is the outline of what I want VBA to do:
 1. Find all "dark blue" lines in the entire PPT presentation. I might need to specify the RGB values of the color.
 2. Find the width and height of each line, multiply by a number I will input, and output the final width and heights.
 3. Near the "dark blue" lines, draw a text box and encode the final width and height. Font color of width is magenta while font color of height is navy blue.

So essentially, what I want is to annotate the dark blue lines I drew with converted width and height. I will provide the conversion factor via user input dialog box.

Any suggested functions or codes to start with? I'll try my best to google the rest.

Thank you very much! :)

Comment: Your question is too broad right now - it's just a project specification.  Take *one part of this* which you don't know how to do, try it out until you get stuck, and then post back with some code, and explain the issue you're having.  That's the type of thing more likely to attract input here.

Answer (score 0):

This code needs some debugging but is gives you an idea of what you  might need.  You might need to check datatype of p and record a macro of adding a textbox to get that linr right.  The definition of variable c is different for older versions of powerpoint.  "c" is then split into Red Green and Blue and Dark blue corresponds to low red and green values vs higher blue one.  I did not bother to colour the text in the text boxes.

```
Dim h as shape
p=inputbox("Enter number",50,50)
for each h as activewindow.selection.sliderange.shapes
c = h.Line.ForeColor.RGB
redco = c Mod 256
greenco = c \ 256 Mod 256
blueco = c \ 65536 Mod 256
if redco<255/3 and greenco<255/3 and blueco>255/2 then
activewindow.selection.sliderange.shapes.Addtextbox("Arial",12,"Line Width=" & h.line.weight & "  Shape/line height=" & p * h.height & "    Shape/line width="  & p * h.width, h.left-50, h.top-50,80,80).select
End if
Next
```

Comment: Thanks @Giles S. I'll get back to you after looking into this. Thanks.